Alternative formula for $\mathbb{E}[X^r]$ using $r\int^\infty_{0} x^{r-1} \mathbb{P}(X > x) \,dx$
I am trying to prove an identity listed in Feller's "An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications | Volume 2" on page 150
$$ \mathbb{E} [X^r] = r\int^\infty_{0} x^{r-1} \mathbb{P}(X > x) \,dx $$
for all nonnegative $X$ and $r > 0$. Using integration by parts, I managed to find the following
$$ \mathbb{E} [X^r] = \lim_{b\to\infty} \left[(F_X(b) - 1)b^r + r\int^b_0 x^{r - 1} \mathbb{P}(X > x) dx \right] $$
I wish to show that the left term vanishes at the limit. Is the identity below true for all $X$?
$$ \lim_{b\to\infty} (F_X(b) - 1)b^r = 0 $$
where $F_X$ is the distribution function of some nonnegative random variable $X$.

I'm not sure how you got that from integration by parts. The claim follows from $EX^r=\int_0^\infty P(X\geq t^{1/r})dt$ and changing variables.

You want to show that
$$
\lim_{b\to\infty} b^r(1-F(b))=\lim_{b\to\infty} b^r\ \mathbb P(X>b)=0
$$
under the assumption that $\mathbb E [X^r]$ exists.
Suppose not. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $\{b_k\}_{k=1,2,\dots}$ converging to infinity such that
$$
b_k^r\ \mathbb P(X>b_k)\ge \epsilon,\quad k=1,2,\dots
$$
We can also assume w.l.o.g. that
$$
b_{k+1}>\left(\frac{2 \mathbb E[ X^r]}\epsilon\right)^{1/r}b_k.
$$
By Markov's inequality, since $h(x)=x^r$ is monotone increasing for $x>0$,
$$
\mathbb P(X_k\ge b_{k+1})=\mathbb P(X_k^r\ge b_{k+1}^r)\le \frac{\mathbb E X_k^r}{b_{k+1}^r}<\frac{\epsilon}{2 b_k^r}.
$$
Hence
$$
\mathbb P(b_k< X\le b_{k+1})=\mathbb P(X>b_k)-\mathbb P(X>b_{k+1})
\ge \frac{\epsilon}{b_k^r}-\frac{\epsilon}{2 b_k^r}=\frac{\epsilon}{2b_k^r}.
$$
Consequently,
\begin{align}
\mathbb {E} X^r&\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb {E}\left[X^r 1_{b_k< X\le b_{k+1}}\right]
\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb {E}\left[b_k^r 1_{b_k< X\le b_{k+1}}\right]
\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^r\mathbb {P}\left(b_k< X\le b_{k+1}\right)
\\ &
\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^r\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2\, b_k^r}=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2}=
\infty
\end{align}
yielding a contradiction.
